# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple when list passed into function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I was looking into returning information about an array, sorry list I am use to Java, but everytime I run it this the outcome with an error of

```
if low_stock > stock_prices[time]:

>>> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

def get_max_profit(stock_prices  = [], *args):

    low_stock = stock_prices[0]
    low_time = 0
    high_stock = stock_prices[1]
    high_time = 0
    profit = high_stock - low_stock

    for time in enumerate(stock_prices):
        if low_stock > stock_prices[time]:
            low_stock = stock_prices[time]
            low_time = time 
        while time > 0:
            if high_stock < stock_prices[time]:
                high_stock = stock_prices[time]
                high_time = time
        if low_time < high_time:
             return profit
        else:
            return 'Negative Balance'
```

Please Help...

Comment: `enumerate(stock_prices)` is an iterable of `(index, value)` tuples.

Comment: @RobertCamb take a look at this as well https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#what-you-wrote

Comment: You also have a suspicious conditional statement at the end of the function. It always returns from the first iteration of the loop, regardless of the size of `stock_prices`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many logical and run-time errors in your code. Your best strategy is to convert the list of prices to a NumPy array. NumPy has some very handy functions for solving your problem:

```
import numpy as np
stock_prices = np.array(stock_prices)

def get_max_profit(stock_prices):        
    high_time = stock_prices.argmax()
    low_time = stock_prices.argmin()
    if low_time < high_time:
        return stock_prices.max() - stock_prices.min()
    else:
        return 'Negative Balance'
```

The last line is actually bad, too, because a function should always return a value of the same type. You may want to replace `'Negative Balance'` with a -1 and sort it out later.